# Interface Builder: determine which element has the initial focus

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I have a Cocoa app with a table view and a few other controls. When the app launches and the window is shown, a blue focus ring is drawn around the table view.

How can I get rid of that focus ring? I'd like nothing to have the focus when the window first shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The window has initialFirstResponder binding that shows which control will be active when the window becomes active. Change the initialFirstResponder or adjust tableview settings in interface builder to hide the focus ring

Comment: I checked, the window has no initialFirstResponder set. Where is the setting in the table view to hide the focus ring?

Comment: It is in view's settings section a bit bellow table view settings.

Comment: Found it. How could I have missed this? Thanks!

Comment: @Mark: Note that hiding the focus ring does not mean it won't have focus. When it has focus, it should have a focus ring, and depending on your app, there's a good chance that the table view *should* have focus initially. If it really shouldn't, set the initial first responder outlet to a different view. (When it isn't set, the window will pick one automatically.)

Comment: @PeterHosey Thanks for the heads-up! I've set the initial first responder to another view, just as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found of stopping any of the controls from being the first responder when a window is first displayed is in the window controller:

**Swift 3:**

```
class YourWindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        // Wait a frame before setting the first responder to be the window itself.
        // We can't just set it right now, because if the first responder is set
        // to the window now the system just interprets that as meaning that we
        // want the default behavior where it automatically selects a view to be
        // the first responder.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            window!.makeFirstResponder(nil)
        }
    }

}
```

It's messy, and sometimes when the window loads you see the focus ring starting to appear on one of the controls for one frame, but I haven't found a better way yet.